# How do I play this mp3 audio on my website when a button is clicked

Tags: python, flask

When trying to play the sound file output.mp3 on my website, no sound plays and i get a error logged that the file could not be found. My sound file is within the website folder so it should have no problem finding it.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text To Speech</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text To Speech Converter</h1>

    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <p>Text:</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="nm"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </form>

    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <script>
        let play = document.getElementById("play");
        function playMusic() {
            let audio = new Audio("/output.mp3");
                audio.play()
                }
                play.addEventListener("click", playMusic);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Python code flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
        return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/submit", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def input():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form["nm"]
        synthesize_text_file(text)
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This should be a problem with how my files are organised:

Root: Templates, python code, css.
Templates: index.html, output.mp3

After running the code and entering a text, it gets converted into sound and gets put into the templates file.

I was expecting for the sound to play, but i get the error that it cannot find the file, i am also running the flask server: http://127.0.0.1:5000/. So might this cause a problem?

Comment: you should ask for js file from the backend, once you got it from backend you can do play part , here i don't see in your backend you are requesting for file.

Answer (score 0):

Static files should be saved in the `static` folder in your project's root directory. So, your file structure should look like this:

```
my-app/
├─ static/
│  ├─ output.mp3
├─ templates/
│  ├─ index.html
├─ app.py
```

You can use `url_for` to access these static files in your HTML pages, e.g.

```js
const audio = new Audio('{{ url_for('static', filename='output.mp3') }}');
```

For a more info, check out Flask's [documentation for static files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/static/).

Answer (score -1):

missing semicolon (;) after audio.play() inside the playMusic function.

see if this fixes the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text To Speech</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text To Speech Converter</h1>

    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <p>Text:</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="nm"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </form>

    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <script>
        let play = document.getElementById("play");
        function playMusic() {
            let audio = new Audio("/output.mp3");
            audio.play();
        }
        play.addEventListener("click", playMusic);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about the backend to server audio file ?

Comment: For some reason the audio still doesn't play, i added the missing semicolon (;) after audio.play() inside the playMusic function, but still no change, in the console logs, it says :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: that should fix the problem i think as long as the path to the mp3 is correct and accessible

Comment: is it inside a folder .. you may need to use directory traversal  using   .../output.mp3

Comment: its currently inside my root folder, which contains templates folder, css and python script. The file updated to a new mp3 file every time i re run the script with a new text, could this affect it?

Comment: can you post your flask app somewhere like pastebin or something and i can take a look at it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ByaVMtYt here is my flask app